# FFTW with large data and few MPI processes

Tags: mpi, fft, large-data, hpc, fftw

#### Problem

I use [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) for computing MPI parallelized in-place 3D FFT's, specifically using [`fftw_mpi_plan_dft_r2c_3d()`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/MPI-Plan-Creation.html), which generally works. Recently I've become interested in mixing large data sizes with few CPU cores / MPI processes. Using 2 processes, the 3D FFT of global size `gridsize*gridsize*gridsize` fails with the error

> [s81n11:31843] *** An error occurred in MPI_Sendrecv
>
> [s81n11:31843] *** reported by process [1582235649,0]
>
> [s81n11:31843] *** on communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 6 DUP FROM 5
>
> [s81n11:31843] *** MPI_ERR_COUNT: invalid count argument
>
> [s81n11:31843] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
>
> [s81n11:31843] ***    and potentially your MPI job)

if I use `gridsize >= 2048`. Note that it works fine using e.g. 1 or 3 processes.

I suspect this comes down to MPI messages in `MPI_Sendrecv()` being limited in size. For 2 processes, the physical size of each local grid is `size = (gridsize/2)*gridsize*(2*(gridsize/2 + 1))`, where the global grid is distributed over the first dimension and the last dimension receives a small amount of [padding](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Multi_002ddimensional-MPI-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html). For `gridsize = 2048`, `size = 1.001*2³²`. I have no problem for `gridsize = 2047`, for which `size = 0.999*2³²`.

1. Where exactly do the problem stem from? It would be nice to point out the exact `unsigned int` (or whatever) culprit.
2. If I was in charge of the MPI calls directly, I could just perform the communication in chunks using several calls. As MPI is called internally by FFTW though, how can I solve this issue? I guess I'm even willing to hack on the FFTW/MPI source if it's not too involved.

Though others must have run into this issue before, I couldn't find anything online about such limits of FFTW. Any references on the topic are appreciated.

I've found the problem using FFTW 3.3.9 with both MPICH 3.3.2 and OpenMPI 4.0.3, running on 64 bit Linux.

#### Example code

Below is an example C code, call it `fft.c`:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fftw3-mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  /* Set grid size */
  ptrdiff_t gridsize = 32;
  if (argc > 1)
    gridsize = atoi(argv[1]);
  ptrdiff_t gridsize_padding = 2*(gridsize/2 + 1);

  /* Initialize MPI */
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  fftw_mpi_init();

  /* Allocate grid */
  ptrdiff_t gridsize_local;
  ptrdiff_t gridsize_local_i, gridstart_local_i;
  ptrdiff_t gridsize_local_j, gridstart_local_j;
  double* grid = fftw_alloc_real(fftw_mpi_local_size_3d_transposed(
    gridsize,
    gridsize,
    gridsize_padding,
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,
    &gridsize_local_i,
    &gridstart_local_i,
    &gridsize_local_j,
    &gridstart_local_j
  ));
  assert(gridsize_local_i == gridsize_local_j);
  gridsize_local = gridsize_local_i;
  if (rank == 0)
    printf("gridsize %td\n", gridsize);
  printf("rank %d got gridsize_local = %td\n", rank, gridsize_local);

  /* Nullify grid */
  ptrdiff_t i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < gridsize_local; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < gridsize; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k < gridsize_padding; k++) {
        grid[(i*gridsize + j)*gridsize_padding + k] = 0.0;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Carry out FFT */
  fftw_plan plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_r2c_3d(
      gridsize,
      gridsize,
      gridsize,
      grid,
      (fftw_complex*) grid,
      MPI_COMM_WORLD,
      FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_MPI_TRANSPOSED_OUT
  );
  fftw_mpi_gather_wisdom(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  fftw_mpi_broadcast_wisdom(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  fftw_execute(plan);

  /* Clean up */
  fftw_free(grid);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
  fftw_mpi_cleanup();
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Assuming you have MPI and FFTW installed and the environment suitably configured, you can compile the above `fft.c` using

```sh
mpicc -I/path/to/fftw/include -I/path/to/mpi/include -c -o fft.o fft.c
mpicc fft.o -o fft -L/path/to/fftw/lib -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/fftw/lib -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -L/path/to/mpi/lib -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/mpi/lib -lmpi
```

To perform a 3D FFT using 2 processes with e.g. a `gridsize` of 64, now do

```sh
mpiexec -n 2 ./fft 64
```

Nothing much will happen, as no results are checked or printed. Running with a `gridsize` of 2048 though will produce the crash after about a minute. **Warning**: Running with a `gridsize` of 2048 will take up 64 GB of memory (!) so you may not be able to test this out.